# Laptop or tablet for custom use case?

Tags: laptop, tablet, performance, battery-life

I have a kind of unique use case, I need about 5 pieces of hardware to access a custom web application and I'm in the process of researching my possibilities.

My main problem is being on a quite low budget ($150-250) and that because the only thing the device would be used for is accessing a mid/high grade web application, so essentially, running a browser, I do not need other resources provided by given device, like a good camera or lots of storage.

The most important properties would be:

- A clear and rather big display. (Minimum 10 inch maybe?)
- Enough RAM for the browser to not lag, freeze.
- Long battery life. (It might be used where power is not directly available.)

Do you have any suggestions? I have looked into the Huawei MediaPad T5 and Lenovo Tab M8 on the tablet side, I've only found very few fitting laptops on used hardware sites.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/193935610926) is a laptop/tablet convertible that has pretty good specs for the price.  It only has 64GB of storage, so it really will be just for web applications, but it has enough storage for Windows updates.  The display is where this laptop excels.  It is a full HD (1920x1080) 11.6 inch touchscreen display, which you will not see on many budget laptops.  In my experience, the speakers on the Gateway laptops are subpar, but the headphone jack should fix this.  It is also in Windows 10 S mode, which you can replace with Windows 10 Home for free.  It even has better IO than a $1500+ MacBook Pro, so that's a plus ;).

I wouldn't bet money on it, but I have seen in some cases the new gateway laptops have an extra RAM and M.2 SSD slot.  I haven't used a 2 in 1 Gateway laptop, however, so don't buy it for this reason.  If the stock specs aren't good enough, don't expect to be able to upgrade it.

I'm not sure how exactly how long the battery would last on this laptop.  My Gateway laptop over 5 hours on a charge, but mine isn't a 2 in 1.

I would highly recommend doing your own research in addition to mine as you know exactly what you are looking for.  Don't just take my word for it.

Comment: Agreed; I'm guessing it was potentially the GWTC116, but it's though to say without info from the OP, especially since the Internet Archive doesn't have this page.